# IdentityServer3 pass Request.ClientCertificate from client request context

Tags: c#, ssl, owin, identityserver3, client-certificates

I have following configuration: some web app with hosted on iis with "Require SSL" parameter set. Also i have authentication service based on IdentityServer3.

I need to pass Request.ClientCertificate.SerialNumber from my web app to IdentityServer in authentication flow.

Here's part of my client config:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    // if signing in, send certificate parameters
                    if(n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
                    {
                        // here i would like to get client certificate
                        var req = n.OwinContext.Request;

                        // and pass it's serial number to IdentityServer someway
                        n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = req.ClientCertificate.SerialNumber
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
          }
```

Is it possible? How can i get current request's ClientCertificate?

Comment: See https://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/11/client-certificate-authentication-middleware-for-katana/ for an example of working with client certs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i've got this working:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
    {
        // if signing in, send certificate parameters
        if(n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
        {
            var RequestContext = n.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.Routing.RequestContext"] as System.Web.Routing.RequestContext;
            if (RequestContext != null)
            {
                var clientCert = RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate;

                // if client authenticated with certificate then extract certificate info and pass it to identity server
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientCert.SerialNumber))
                {
                    var sn = clientCert.SerialNumber.Replace("-", "");

                    // Acr on IdentityServer side explodes by spaces. To prevent splitting values with spaces made some replaces
                    n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "cert:" + sn + " " + clientCert.Subject.Replace(" ","_*_").Replace(",_*_"," ");
                }
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    },
}
```